# Optimize Sitecore Lucene / Solr query

Tags: linq, solr, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to optimize some Lucene/Solr queries that are done via the Sitecore ContentSearch API.  Specifically, when it comes to searching a MultiListField.

Environment:
Sitecore 8.1u2, Solr

I have the following Method for querying the values of a multilistfield:

```
public static Expression<Func<SearchResultItem, bool>> MultiFieldContainsExpression(IEnumerable<string> fieldNames, IEnumerable<string> ids)
{
   //fieldNames = ["field_A", "field_X"]
   //ids = [GUID_A, GUID_X]

   Expression<Func<SearchResultItem, bool>> expression = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
   foreach (string fieldname in fieldNames)
   {
      ids.ForEach(id =>
      {
         expression = expression.Or(i => i[fieldName].Contains(IdHealper.NormalizeGuid(id, true)));
      });
   }

   return expression;
}
```

The resulting Lucene query looks like this:

```
((field_A:(*GUID_A*) OR field_A:(*GUID_X*) OR field:_X:(*GUID_A*) OR field_X:(*GUID_X*)))
```

I want the query to be more like this (or even better if possible):

```
((field_A:(*GUID_A* OR *GUID_X*) OR (field_X:(*GUID_A* OR *GUID_X*)))
```

Basically, to check if the array of values in the field contains any value from another array.  Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore by default indexs a multilist field as a space separated list of lowercase Guids (Guid.ToString("N")). It could be useful to denormalize the relationship and store the item name or content within the item document through the use of a Computed Field. With the Computed Field it can iterate over the referenced items and turn them into a single field containing their names. You’ll still want to keep the Guid field around for cases when you want to limit the results to just a particular referenced item for the case where you know the exact Guid.